# Why there is no islam.stackexchange but judaism.stackexchange exists?

Tags: discussion, status-norepro

Actually the title is the question.

Also assuming the answer I ask another question: why then judaism.stackexchange appeared before islam.stackexchange? Does Judaism worth to be more popular/known then Islam?

And yes, I'm neither Islamist nor Muslim nor Judaist, have never been in holy land and know very little about both religions. But I see how everything related to Judaism is accelerated everywhere recently. It makes me think about it. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: See http://islam.stackexchange.com/

Comment: see also http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1370/759

Comment: As J. C. Salomon said in his answer, Stack Exchange sites arise from groups of people who are interested in a topic taking action to start a site.  It's not top-down, there's no prioritization, and your belief that this site was somehow accelerated is mistaken.

Answer (score 8):

A community of questioners and answerers grew up around this site earlier than any did on [christianity.stackexchange.com](http://christianity.stackexchange.com) or [islam.stackexchange.com](http://islam.stackexchange.com), both of which exist but are in Beta.